# How to set username and password for SVN repository in Xcode ?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, svn

I'm new to SVN when committing the code to svn repository it was not asking username and password and it will raise issue showing author name was empty in repository commit history. How could set for username every time while committing the code to svn repository in Xcode ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run `svn info <REPOSITORY-URL> -username <USERNAME>` and the `<USERNAME>` will be specified as `svn:author` for your commits.

The actual problem is that your server allows anonymous and non-authenticated access. I guess that your admin may want to reconsider that and make the server require authentication or at least reject commits with empty `svn:author` property. Users should not be able to enter arbitrary usernames / commit author names. How are you going to distinguish was an author of some revision in future? How are you going to search repository history for commits made by a particular user if this user can enter anything he wants as his username?